# Setting a radio button when a user click on "input type="file"

Tags: jquery, forms, file-upload, input

My form look something like this:

```
[ radio ] Use your current picture
[ radio ] Use the sites default

SELECT THIS ONE DYNAMICALLY --> [ radio ] Upload a picture from your computer
---------------- [BrowseButton]
```

The only problem with this is that when a user clicks on either the input field itself ("----"), or the Browse button, the corresponding radio button does not become select (which is expected). I'm trying to attach Javascript events to the field, but nothing seems to be working.

Not sure if it really matters, but the backend is .NET and this is the code that's being used to generate the field:

```
<li>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbUpload" GroupName="avatar" runat="server" Text="Upload a new picture from your computer" />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" /> Maximum file size: 4 MB.
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="FileUploadMessages" runat="server">
</li>
```

Which spits out the following HTML:

```
<li>
    <input type="radio" value="rbUpload" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$avatar" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_rbUpload"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_rbUpload">Upload a new picture from your computer</label>
    <input type="file" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_fileUpload" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$fileUpload"> Maximum file size: 4 MB.
</li>
```

I'm aware that these types of fields are "read only", but that shouldn't be an issue here...right? I've tried attaching jQuery events such as `.click`, but they don't seem to work. See here:

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_fileUpload").click(function() {
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_rbUpload").click(); // sets radio
})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `change` event, like this:

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_fileUpload").change(function() {
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_rbUpload").click(); // sets radio
})
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that, but I guess not. That works great! I think I may have not actually *selected* a file, which probably led me to believe it was not working.

Comment: Seems that 'input type="file"' is some sort of rogue input field for browsers. Styling it is another issue in itself.